# Robocopy switches for incremental drive backup?

Tags: windows, backup, robocopy

I have two hard drives:

G: is an external USB drive connected to a Windows 10 PC
H: is a network drive (another USB drive connected to the USB port of the home network router's USB port)

I have copied all files and sub-folders from G:/my_data_folder onto H:/my_data_folder.  Right now, H:/my_data_folder is an exact copy of G:/my_data_folder.

Now I want to create a Robocopy command that I can run periodically on the Win10 PC, that will copy from G: to H:

- any file/folder in G:/my_data_folder that doesn't already exist in H:/my_data_folder
- any file in G:/my_data_folder that does already exist in H:/my_data_folder but is a more recent version (ie, has been saved more recently).  This newly copied file will over-write the older file on H:.

My understanding of Robocopy is that NOT copying existing files of the same date/time is the default behavior, so I don't need to explicitly exclude them.

I do NOT want H:/my_data_folder to mirror G:/my_data_folder.  That is, never erase anything from H:/my_data_folder, even if it is now absent from G:/my_data_folder.

I don't need a log file, but I want to see what it did on screen.

Here's my attempt to compose the appropriate robocopy command:

```
robocopy g:/my_data_folder h:/my_data_folder /e /np /fft /mt:8 /z /r:5 /w:5
```

where:

- /e = copy even empty directories
- /np = no file copy progress - don't need it
- /fft = in case of any date/time errors due to network drive
- /mt:8 = use 8 concurrent threads to speed things up
- /z = restartable mode so it can recover from an interrupted transfer
- /r:5 = try maximum 5 restarts
- /w:5 = wait 5 seconds between restarts

Will this do what I want?  Have I missed any critical switches for such a task?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `/mt:8` I believe 8 is the default. I've bumped this up to 32 and have had really good success with performance. The range is 1-128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is perfect as it is.

Just to address the slightly confusing "use `/XX` just in case" argument made in harrymc's answer:

"*To avoid deletions in the target folder, I suggest to add the `/XX` switch. This is supposed to be the default, but I would add it explicitly just in case.*"

I recommend against adding redundant switches "just in case". The `/XX` switch will do nothing in your situation, other than create confusion.

The [page](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) cited in the other answer clearly explains what the purpose of that switch is:

"`/XX` (exclude extra) **If used in conjunction with /Purge or /Mir**, the exclude extra switch will take precedence and prevent any files being deleted from the destination."

As your script has neither the `/MIR` nor the `/PURGE` switches, we can say with 100% certainty that adding `/XX` "just in case` is redundant.

I've been using Robocopy for years and have pushed around many terabytes of data, all without ever using the `/XX` switch. Robocopy has never once deleted a single "extra" file.

Further clarification can be seen [here](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1370).

Just wanted to clear that up!

Answer (score -1):

To avoid deletions in the target folder, I suggest to add the `/xx` switch.
This is supposed to be the default, but I would add it explicitly just in case.

```
/xx     Excludes extra files and directories.
```

This switch is further [described](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) as:

```
/XX : eXclude "eXtra" files and dirs (present in destination but not source)
      This will prevent any deletions from the destination. (this is the default)
```